# how to grab actual links directed by hrefs

Tags: java, html, parsing, href

I'm parsing the html code of a webpage and grabbing all the links mentioned as hrefs using regex, but some websites for instance wikipedia, mention certain hrefs in the html code as a paraphrase 
for example:

code says:

`href="#cite_note-Types_of_Test_Item_Formats-`

but link is actually:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(assessment)#cite_note-Types_of_Test_Item_Formats-15

how can I get to these links using only webpage source?

EDIT: coding in java

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: What language are you parsing *with*?

Comment: The anchor (#) refers to the current URL... as long as there is no javascript involved this should be fairly easy.

Comment: For JS you could you use `window.location` and append the href if needed. -- In what language are you parsing the html ?

Answer (score 2):

They're not paraphrasings, they're fragment identifiers. The `#` introduces an identifier for a fragment of a page. So what you've quoted is a relative URL for the current page, with a different fragment identifier. There's more in the [Wikipedia page about URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) and the RFCs it links to.

Note that fragments don't necessarily only show up on their own. They can be in any URL, relative or absolute. If you're going to handle URLs, you'll have to undrstand how to resolve relative URLs. For instance, if we assume we're on the page `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`, then:

- `#frag`
  resolves to
  `http://example.com/foo/bar.html#frag`
- `../alt.html`
  =>
  `http://example.com/foo/alt.html`
- `/bonzo/nifty#stuff`
  =>
  `http://example.com/bonzo/nifty#stuff`
- `//stackoverflow.com/questions/8110960/8110987#8110987` (note the lack of protocol)
  =>
  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110960/8110987#8110987`
  (yes, [really](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html))

...etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

On wikipedia, that just refers to a part on the page (you are currently on), the browser will just scroll down to the anchor for you.
on some sites though, like twitter. my account for example
http://twitter.com/#!/msundb (and http://twitter.com/msundb that forwards to it)
is actualy just the root of twitter.com. everything after the #! is there to tell the javascript on the page what content it should load. It even has the link rel canonical set to "/" telling google that it is the startpage (although it isnt).

So how you should interpret the links depends on what you are doing with them.